# How do I parse through an xml string in python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse through this large xml string in order to get data on the x and y coordinates (seen in the event elements as "coord x" and "coord y"). At the moment I am just trying to get the xml element tree library to read the data in the xml string, but it is returning "none".

Note: the "xml" variable looks something like ''' {insert xml data here}'''.strip()

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

value = et.fromstring(xml).find('quarter/events/event')

print(value)
```

I would like the final result after parsing to look something like a dataframe with the locations, time, and type of shot as the columns and the player who shot as the rows. I think I understand the logic behind the parsing however because I have done something similar with html, but I just want to get my code to pick up the value in the string.

The xml data generally looks something like this and I want to extract the data everytime it says something like event_type="threepointmiss", or any of the other variations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generation started @ 2022-06-29 00:39:09 UTC -->
<game xmlns="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/basketball/pbp-v7.0.xsd" id="6d2c3191-8604-4026-84d3-32f36d042a8e" status="closed" coverage="full" scheduled="2021-10-22T02:00:00+00:00" duration="2:28" attendance="18064" lead_changes="10" times_tied="6" clock="00:00" quarter="4" track_on_court="true" reference="0022100016" entry_mode="WEBSOCKET" sr_id="sr:match:28808644" clock_decimal="00:00" home_team="583ec825-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" away_team="583ecdfb-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c">
  <time_zones venue="US/Pacific" home="US/Pacific" away="US/Pacific"/>
  <scoring>
    <home name="Warriors" alias="GSW" market="Golden State" id="583ec825-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" points="115" bonus="true" sr_id="sr:team:3428" reference="1610612744"/>
    <away name="Clippers" alias="LAC" market="LA" id="583ecdfb-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" points="113" bonus="true" sr_id="sr:team:3425" reference="1610612746"/>
  </scoring>
  <quarter id="4a215fde-43af-4e89-b89b-6136db986c0f" number="1" sequence="1">
    <scoring times_tied="0" lead_changes="0">
      <home name="Warriors" market="Golden State" id="583ec825-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" points="44" reference="1610612744"/>
      <away name="Clippers" market="LA" id="583ecdfb-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" points="27" reference="1610612746"/>
    </scoring>
    <events>
      <event id="6d812a9b-1b84-4f9b-b7d4-c4b5bb378a13" clock="12:00" updated="2021-10-22T02:12:23Z" wall_clock="2021-10-22T02:12:23Z" sequence="1634868743093" home_points="0" away_points="0" clock_decimal="12:00" number="5002" event_type="lineupchange">
        <description>Clippers lineup change (Paul George, Eric Bledsoe, Reggie Jackson, Ivica Zubac, Marcus Morris Sr.)</description>
        <attribution name="Clippers" market="LA" id="583ecdfb-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" sr_id="sr:team:3425" reference="1610612746"/>
        <on_court>
          <home name="Warriors" market="Golden State" id="583ec825-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" sr_id="sr:team:3428" reference="1610612744">
            <player full_name="Andrew Wiggins" jersey_number="22" id="77c425f0-0fce-4fab-bd1e-c915c8fb5bc7" sr_id="sr:player:607676" reference="203952"/>
            <player full_name="Draymond Green" jersey_number="23" id="5e5099d1-4a58-43f2-8d03-f2ae5dd49337" sr_id="sr:player:608020" reference="203110"/>
            <player full_name="Kevon Looney" jersey_number="5" id="ebb50069-6fdf-4c07-9a21-a63d5c814536" sr_id="sr:player:852188" reference="1626172"/>
            <player full_name="Stephen Curry" jersey_number="30" id="8ec91366-faea-4196-bbfd-b8fab7434795" sr_id="sr:player:608110" reference="201939"/>
            <player full_name="Jordan Poole" jersey_number="3" id="2ed2f76f-5a2f-4d79-ab7c-e84a8a42dc21" sr_id="sr:player:1316820" reference="1629673"/>
          </home>
          <away name="Clippers" market="LA" id="583ecdfb-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" sr_id="sr:team:3425" reference="1610612746">
            <player full_name="Paul George" jersey_number="13" id="db09f372-9a17-4889-add7-bf8a75ab6da6" sr_id="sr:player:608072" reference="202331"/>
            <player full_name="Eric Bledsoe" jersey_number="12" id="8cee3c73-f765-4000-882d-0c6d0b8acbe3" sr_id="sr:player:607996" reference="202339"/>
            <player full_name="Reggie Jackson" jersey_number="1" id="7b745dde-a011-45a8-98a8-460a9facb3ce" sr_id="sr:player:607852" reference="202704"/>
            <player full_name="Ivica Zubac" jersey_number="40" id="2da18268-82d4-4b40-a296-7ceddd435d0b" sr_id="sr:player:994293" reference="1627826"/>
            <player full_name="Marcus Morris Sr." jersey_number="8" id="4d7cb358-0fec-482f-9f57-92c39e8bf214" sr_id="sr:player:607910" reference="202694"/>
          </away>
        </on_court>
      </event>   
<event id="098b73e8-fda6-472c-aa16-3588ed4115bc" clock="11:35" updated="2021-10-22T23:27:30Z" wall_clock="2021-10-22T02:13:08Z" sequence="1634868788200" home_points="0" away_points="0" clock_decimal="11:35" number="9" event_type="threepointmiss">
            <description>Jordan Poole misses three point jump shot</description>
            <attribution name="Warriors" market="Golden State" id="583ec825-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" team_basket="right" sr_id="sr:team:3428" reference="1610612744"/>
            <location coord_x="849" coord_y="92" action_area="outsideleft"/>
            <on_court>
              <home name="Warriors" market="Golden State" id="583ec825-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" sr_id="sr:team:3428" reference="1610612744">
                <player full_name="Andrew Wiggins" jersey_number="22" id="77c425f0-0fce-4fab-bd1e-c915c8fb5bc7" sr_id="sr:player:607676" reference="203952"/>
                <player full_name="Draymond Green" jersey_number="23" id="5e5099d1-4a58-43f2-8d03-f2ae5dd49337" sr_id="sr:player:608020" reference="203110"/>
            <player full_name="Kevon Looney" jersey_number="5" id="ebb50069-6fdf-4c07-9a21-a63d5c814536" sr_id="sr:player:852188" reference="1626172"/>
            <player full_name="Stephen Curry" jersey_number="30" id="8ec91366-faea-4196-bbfd-b8fab7434795" sr_id="sr:player:608110" reference="201939"/>
            <player full_name="Jordan Poole" jersey_number="3" id="2ed2f76f-5a2f-4d79-ab7c-e84a8a42dc21" sr_id="sr:player:1316820" reference="1629673"/>
          </home>
          <away name="Clippers" market="LA" id="583ecdfb-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" sr_id="sr:team:3425" reference="1610612746">
            <player full_name="Paul George" jersey_number="13" id="db09f372-9a17-4889-add7-bf8a75ab6da6" sr_id="sr:player:608072" reference="202331"/>
            <player full_name="Eric Bledsoe" jersey_number="12" id="8cee3c73-f765-4000-882d-0c6d0b8acbe3" sr_id="sr:player:607996" reference="202339"/>
            <player full_name="Reggie Jackson" jersey_number="1" id="7b745dde-a011-45a8-98a8-460a9facb3ce" sr_id="sr:player:607852" reference="202704"/>
            <player full_name="Ivica Zubac" jersey_number="40" id="2da18268-82d4-4b40-a296-7ceddd435d0b" sr_id="sr:player:994293" reference="1627826"/>
            <player full_name="Marcus Morris Sr." jersey_number="8" id="4d7cb358-0fec-482f-9f57-92c39e8bf214" sr_id="sr:player:607910" reference="202694"/>
          </away>
        </on_court>
        <statistics>
          <fieldgoal made="false" shot_type="jump shot" three_point_shot="true" shot_distance="24.99">
            <team name="Warriors" market="Golden State" id="583ec825-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c" sr_id="sr:team:3428" reference="1610612744"/>
            <player full_name="Jordan Poole" jersey_number="3" id="2ed2f76f-5a2f-4d79-ab7c-e84a8a42dc21" sr_id="sr:player:1316820" reference="1629673"/>
          </fieldgoal>
        </statistics>
      </event>
```

Comment: The XML has a default namespace (defined by `xmlns="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/basketball/pbp-v7.0.xsd"`, that you need to take into account. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces.

Comment: I adjusted it for the namespace, but it still is reading as no data

Comment: What did you adjust? Please edit the question.

Comment: whats the full xml? share the url that returns this data.